# speech recognition in python times out

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

when I try to run my code and talk into the mic I wait for about 10s and then this error pops up `TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`

this is my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def wakecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("say something")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
    print(query)
    return query
```

I also tried running the test that the library offers `python -m speech_recognition` I got the same error

Comment: what is `sr`? what library are you using? Have you checked is the audio variable actually contains any audio? so you can reduce the problem to either the audio not being recorded or the recorded audio not being recognized.

Comment: I think it is not being recognized but how can I fix it

Comment: Have you tried different audios, like a very clear "Hello" and see if it works then? Or does it always fail no matter the audio? You need to do a lot of testing to determine the cause of the error and include what you have already tried in the question. For example you can replace the microphone code with code that loads the audio from a file with a very clear sentence. So then you can 100% discard that the problem comes from the mic, since you can then guarantee that the audio passed to the recognizer is good.

Comment: I tried and it got something from the mic but then when it was trying to understand the mic input that error occurs

Comment: please read my comment and try the suggestions I gave you. Have a good day.